# Accesskey not working for h1 element in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am trying to use accesskey for a div element and a h1 element. I gave these elements tabindex attribute as `tabindex="0"`. Accessing this element with the shortcut key given in accesskey works in firefox and IE but not in chrome. Does anyone have any idea about this? Any help provided is greatly appreciated.

Please see below the sample code:

```html
<h1 tabindex="0" accesskey="t">Topics</h1>
<a href="https://www.google.com" accesskey="g">Test Google Link</a>
```

If you copy the above code into a html file, save it and open it using chrome, you can tab through both 'Topics' header and 'Test Google Link' link element. The link can be accessed using Alt+g, but the header cannot be accessed using Alt+t.

Comment: Please share the relevant part(s) of your code

Comment: Added code. Please check out again.

Comment: There is no `div` in your code and you are asking about why things are not working with a `div`??!! This is apart from the reason as to why would you want an accesskey on a `div`, or even `hx` for that matter? Accesskeys are for commandAction, and what would a commandAction be for a `div` or a header?

Comment: I mentioned in the body of question that I want to use it on a h1 element as well. I wanted to keep it simple, so I just put a h1 element, as this also illustrates my issue perfectly.

The accesskey attribute specifies a shortcut key to activate/focus an element. I want to do just that, focus on this element, so that I can allow the users to quickly jump to this section of the page. Can you provide a source for what you say, i.e., commandAction for accesskeys?

Answer (score 2):

There are different shortcuts for different browser and different operating systems.
You can have a look at this table for more information [Accesskey Table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am aware of the different modifier keys for different browsers and I am using the correct modifier for chrome (Alt). It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is now 6 years old, but as of now, access to the `h1` using the access key <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> works in current Chrome (81) as expected.